# use awk to convert bytes to Kbytes in network output

Tags: macos, bash, awk, sar, geektool

Attempting to use geektool to show average Kbytes in and out on my mac

Thinking to use sar awk and grep for this but sar outputs in bytes and I want Kbytes

sar -n DEV 1 1 | grep -i 'average.*en0' 
(obviously would use more data but 1 1 is fast)

Sample output

```
Average:   en0            1            68           2           132
```

sar -n DEV 1 1 | grep -i 'average.*en0' | awk '{print $4, $6}'

Sample output

```
68 132
```

How would I use awk to convert this byte/ps output to Kbytes/ps?

**Answer:**

```
sar -n DEV 1 1 | grep -i 'average.*en0'| awk '{printf "i: %.2f Kbps\no: %.2f Kbps\n", $4 / 1024, $6 / 1024 }'
```

This replaces doing it with netstat with 11 lines of code, which I think was less accurate and alot more code

Comment: simply use $4/1024 and $6/1024, or a printf if you want a fancier formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{printf "%.2f %.2f\n", $4 / 1024, $6 / 1024 }'
```

will print kilobytes with two decimal points.

```
$ line="Average:   en0            1            68           2           132"
$ echo "$line" | awk '{printf "%.2f %.2f\n", $4 / 1024, $6 / 1024 }'
0.07 0.13
```

Answer (score 0):

In my sar (sysstat 10.0.5), `$4` is `txpck/s` and `$6` is `txkB/s`. Thus, dividing by 1000 resp. 1024 would give `Ktxpck/s` and `txMiB/s`:

`sar -n DEV 1 1 | awk '/Average.*en0/ {print $4/1000, $6/1024}'`